# Problem with data input. CSV with polygon coordinates to polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, excel

I have a .CSV file with information about polygons (which are squares), represented by the coordinates of the four points that shape a square (4 pairs of long/lat coordinates)

All are in one column, with this format: "[[43.65709678906501,-8.143885243142325],[43.67871793261613,-8.022902253073957],[43.76597461330047,-8.050819877487672],[43.74431550733586,-8.171971006002625]]".

Notice that i have all that coordinates on the same column.

Do you know any way to convert that information directly to polygons in QGIS?

Comment: Do you only have the geometry string in between brackets in your .csv or do you have the point coordinates to generate a geometry? With "delimited text layer" you can import Polygons from .csv files. For that you need to select WKT Geometry definition and have your geometry as a WKT formatted string, which in your case is: 'POLYGON((43.6570967890650 -8.143885243142325,43.67871793261613 -8.022902253073957,43.76597461330047 -8.050819877487672,43.74431550733586 -8.171971006002625))'.  "43,..." being longitude. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45011384/how-to-use-wkt-to-draw-polygon-in-qgis

Comment: Ideally, you would want your current format to be reworked or processed to match the WKT format

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved. I formatted the data to WKT, and then I added to QGIS as CSV.